# Translation of 'Takana'

Tags: translation, derabanan

What would a fitting colloquially accepted  translation of the word takana be? Assuming we are dealing of course with a rabbinic decree and so as to convey the intent as apposed to 'gzeira', 'syag', 'mishmeres' and such.

Comment: Literally, the word "takana" comes from "tikun" meaning "to fix" or "to correct". This is not like the adage "If it ain't broke don't fix it", as nothing is, necessarily "broken". However, in a sense, a takana is placed often, to improve the way people have been doing things. In a way it is like an oil change for your car. The car may not be broken, but you "fix" the car by changing the oil so that it runs better.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45423

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically distinguish, I would go with [corrective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/corrective[noun]):

> something that corrects or counteracts something undesirable

The Rabbis established a corrective. Bishul Yisroel is a Rabbinic corrective against intermarriage.

But with the caveat that from my observation the distinction between takkana and gezeira is not regarded as important in many places and thus would really not necessarily lead to a better quality translation to translate them differently based on the original word choice.

Comment: @ Yishai You got me thinking though. Is there a similar noun based around the word strengh? Not sure if its a better, just wondering.

Comment: @user6591, I think [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) answers such questions.

Comment: @ Yishai- so the linguist J.J. Obermark at English.se suggested reinforcement, or reinforce. I kinda like it. What do you say?

Comment: @user6591, it works for the second example ("a reinforcement against intermarriage"), but "established a reinforcement" doesn't make sense to me (but I'm no linguist). But I think they were saying over there that there is some domain specificity here.

Comment: @Yishai- they did say there is domain specificity here. I'm stuck in no mans land between two sites! I need a religous linguist. Like my seventh grade teacher. Too bad he was such a jerk:) but anyways..... how about enacted a reinforcement? Sound better?

Comment: @user6591, sounds reasonable to me.